# COUNT(id) instead of COUNT(*) in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-pagination

I'm  paginating a list view for a model with many fields, so it takes a lot of time to execute `MyModel.objects.filter('some filter').count()`, because on SQL level it runs

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable
```

instead of:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM mytable
```

even if I write explicitly

```
MyModel.objects.only('id').count()
```

How can I make Django run `COUNT(id)` on `.count()`?

Update:

I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: are you sure that it will be faster?

Comment: It's unlikely that there's any real performance difference between `count(*)` and `count(id)`. Don't bother changing that, you won't gain anything. `count` is simply slow on postgresql due to MVCC model. However you can quickly estimate the number of rows: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate Or you can keep track of numbers of rows in a separate table/cache.

Comment: i guess you won't find much difference in terms of speed but obviously something new to learn .

Comment: Are you sure it is slow because of `*` vs `id`, not because of a missing index on the field you are filtering?

Comment: @freakish You are right, looks like I have to use endless pagination or some other trick to avoid executing `count()`

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
MyModel.objects.filter('some filter').values_list("id).count()
```

This will do this query:

```
select count(id) from MyModel
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using an aggregate query:

```
from django.db import models
MyObject.objects.all().aggregate(models.Count('id'))['id__count']
```

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT(id)` is roughly the equivalent of:

```
MyModel.objects.exclude(id=None).count()
```

this will add extra step to count the table fields, which is not the case for `COUNT(*)`